# What is the writing on this sticky note tile?

Tags: piece-information

Is it a bullet-point list? Or some kind of poem? Or non-words?

LEGO Tile 1 x 1 with Black Writing (Sticky Note / Post-It) with Groove (25389)

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

LEGO seems to be serious about the fan base, so I wrote 'em, and gave 'em the  task...

[image]

...And they just wrote back.

[image]

So, a recap-y-cap:

- Doesn't mean anything.
- The letters are initials of some LEGO designers,
- Which designers, (they can't tell).
- Done to fill up space that requires letters (since a real memo note needs some sort of lettering symbols).
- The smile face and the question mark is just flair, or gibberish to
  make it look (more) like a note.
- The circles in front of each line is to represent a check box.

Original poster was right 2 out of 3 speculative reasons behind this piece's creation.  Good job *[Ben](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/10154/what-is-the-writing-on-this-sticky-note-tile)*.

Task complete, and we're very impressed with Joseph's prompt reply from LEGO Customer Service. Thanks again Joe Joe, and now we're off to finish the LEGO survey on "How they did today"...

[image]
[image]
[image]
No, no. You're welcome LEGO, and thanks for *your* help ;).  Later!

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to ask LEGO about this and share the answer Rin - as Joseph mentions in his response it's fairly common practice for the set or piece designer to include their initials for any required text if they want a bit more flair than just wiggly lines.

Comment: That is an awesome answer, thanks a lot! And what a treat to get such a detailed response from LEGO ❤️I guess it helped that your question to them was also A+, thanks again!

Answer (score 7):

First trace of that piece is in LEGO Olivia's Exploration Car Set 41116. It featured stickied on an astronomy-oriented map.

[image]

Probably a bullet point list, and the second word might be `Mars ?`. No idea about the first one

It was also released in other sets at around the same time, one of those is Emma Creative Workshop 41115-1

[image]

In that case the sticky note is in a girly room/workshop, and it could conceivably be a list of two character names, `Ian` and `Marc`, as @V2Blast said in the commands. These sets are part of the Heartlake stuff of LEGO Friends, I don't know if there are two characters with these names.

And, in the end, it's probably left vague deliberately, after all it's LEGO, where we are supposed to create new stuff from their bricks, not be constrained by the sticky note's words. As an examples this sticky notes brick is also used in a LEGO Ideas (Old Fishing Store), where it is on top of the cash register, and it's clearly not used for what's written on the note (Ian, Marc or Mars), just as a generic sticky note.

Comment: 'ear', maybe...?

Comment: I thought maybe Ian, like a character name, but I couldn't verify that theory

Comment: Looks like "Ian" and "Marc?" though I'm not sure how that fits the set.